# is there any 3(i) objection under patents act for the respective claim mentioned in body?

Tags: prosecution, national-stage

28. A percutaneous method of treating the heart of a patient in a manner
    designed to promote normal sinus rhythm, comprising:
    directing an ablation catheter including a distal end percutaneously into the
    vascular system including the left atrium of the heart of a patient, the distal end including an
    ablating tip portion operative to allow selective ablation of tissue,
    percutaneously directing a guiding device comprising a template wire, having
    a lengthwise axis along a proximal portion, into the vascular system and the left atrium of
    the heart of the patient, the guiding device including a template portion at a location distal to
    the proximal portion and extending laterally relative to the lengthwise axis;
    temporarily anchoring the guiding device on tissue proximate to the tissue to
    be ablated, and
    guiding the ablating tip portion along the template portion of the guiding
    device while ablating heart tissue within the left atrium along a pattern designed to promote
    normal sinus rhythm.
29. The method of claim 28, wherein the guiding device further comprises a
    positioning catheter operatively coupled with the ablation catheter and further coupled with
    the template wire, wherein guiding the ablating tip portion further comprises:
    moving the positioning catheter along the template portion of the template
    wire to assist with applying at least a portion of the pattern designed to promote normal
    sinus rhythm.
30. The method of claim 28, wherein temporarily anchoring the guiding device
    further comprises temporarily anchoring a distal tip portion of the template wire.
31. The method of claim 28, wherein the template wire is preformed with a three
    dimensional shape including a tissue anchoring portion and a template portion along which
    the ablation catheter is guided, and the channel further comprises a lumen extending
    lengthwise through the ablation catheter, and the method further comprises:
    extend ng the template wire from the lumen of the ablation catheter to
    transform the template wire from a straightened condition in the lumen of the ablation
    catheter to the three dimensional shape including the tissue anchoring portion and the
    template portion configured to guide the application of at least a portion of the pattern.

Comment: First, please provide a link to the actual patent or application. Second, please explain what you find objectionable about the claims. Third, what country are we dealing with? Otherwise I’m going to have to flag to close as being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the question is regarding Indian patent.

Yes, the above claim would result in a sec 3(i) rejection as that section wouldn't allow the claims related to diagnostic and therapeutic methods. As far as my experience with Indian patent office granted only claims for devices but not treatment/ diagnostic method.